# ForeFont TMG 2010 - Block Youtube

Tags: firewall

I want to block youtube with TMG 2010

I try with url name

youtube.com/* or  *.youtube.com  or  youtube.com:443  or  youtube.com:443/*  or  *.youtube.*

...

I aslo add content fliter

video/mp4

video/x-flv

video/x-ms-asf

and stop Flash player

application/x-shockwave-flash

1. User cannot access www.youtube.com directly but they can access youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxx and view video without problem.
2. User can access youtube.com and view video without any problem.

Please help me slove this problem.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a forward zone called youtube.com on your internal DNS and give it IP of 127.0.0.1 or your can make denied page and pointing to it. This worked for me.